# What show did Yakko, Wakko, and Dot make frequent silent cameos in?

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, crossovers, cameo, animaniacs

*Animaniacs* was an animated TV show made in the 90's about the Warner siblings, Yakko, Wakko, and Dot.  But I don't think that is the only TV show I've seen Yakko, Wakko, and Dot in.  I have a distinct memory of these three characters appearing in another 90's animated TV show, where they were often shown running around, with no dialogue.  Can someone help me identify it?

At least my recollection is that the  show is *Tiny Toon Adventures*.  Now *Tiny Adventures* ran from 1990 to 1992, whereas *Animaniacs* ran from 1993 to 1998.  But they were both Warner Bros. shows, so it's possible that toward the end of the *Tiny Toon Adventures* run they were showing cameos of *Animaniacs* characters to lead into the new show.  Can anyone confirm this?

Now it's possible that I'm misremembering, and the show I'm thinking of is actually *Pinky and the Brain*.  After all, *Pinky and the Brain* was a spinoff of *Animaniacs*, so it makes sense that you would have *Animaniacs* cameos in *Pinky and the Brain*.

Comment: They might also have appeared in [Freakazoid](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111970/?ref_=nv_sr_1), another related show.

Comment: Found out they often cameo in [Rita and Runt](http://animaniacs.wikia.com/wiki/Rita_and_Runt) as well. Although the most likely appeared in Freakazoid and all Warner Animations of that time.